# Windows 10 missing from grub after Ubuntu update

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, grub

So I updated Ubuntu to 14.04 a few days ago and I just noticed Windows 10 went missing from the grub menu options. I tried multiple variations of `update-grub` and tried using boot-repair, too, but nothing fixed it. [Here's the pastebin from boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15415342/).

I'm at a loss as to what to try next. Any help?

EDIT: After reading a few suggestions elsewhere, I tried editing `/etc/grub.b/40_common`, and here are its current contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply     type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to     change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Windows 10" {
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Windows 102" {
    set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
    chainloader +1
}
```

But booting from either "Windows 10x" option doesn't work.

Option 1 (set root='(hd0,msdos1)') displays this error (imgur .com/AbymY1r.jpg), which stays onscreen for about half a minute or until I `ctrl+alt+del` out of it (which restarts the computer and goes back to grub).

Option 2, on the other hand, gives off this error:

```
BOOTMGR is missing
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del do restart
```

I tried using the repair options through the Windows 10 installation disk, and assorted commands within it (e.g. `bootrec /RebuildBcd`, `bootrec /FixMbr` and `bootrec /FixBoot`), but all that did was screw up grub again, and I ended up not being able to boot to neither Ubuntu nor Windows. I made grub come back by using the Ubuntu Live CD, now I'm back to the same problem, except for these new Windows 10 entries I manually added to grub.

This is the output for `fsbkl -f`:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL           MOUNTPOINT
sda                           
├─sda1 ntfs   System Reserved 
├─sda2 ntfs                   
├─sda3                        
├─sda5 swap                   [SWAP]
└─sda6 ext4                   /
sr0
```

EDIT 2: SOLVED!

So, I managed to solve it by following Christian_Sosa's answer at [MS support](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/the-boot-configuration-data-for-your-pc-is-missing/2cff8cea-bbac-4929-9d36-a349a6c64324), basically run `chkdsk` on the windows drives and then try startup repair. In my case, `chkdsk` did the trick.

Comment: Keep `/etc` under version control. If comes in handy if your config changes and you don't know why, and/or you want to change it back. And what good do you think `update-grub` is doing to do? This just installs GRUB. What makes you think GRUB is not installed? Check and see what packages were updated. `/var/log/dpkg.log`, and also the files in `/var/log/apt`, particularly `history.log`. Note that `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is assembled from files in `/etc/grub.d`.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in the logs you mentioned.

Here are their contents:
``/var/log/dpkg.log`` : http://pastebin.com/a7Zvzyun
``/var/log/apt/history.log`` : http://pastebin.com/spAYRQCB

Comment: Put the command and its output from `history.log` in the question. It's relevant. I wouldn't bother with `dpkg.log`. It looks like GRUB was updated, but it was a minor update. Do you have backups of the `/etc` directory? If so, you could check what changed. In any case, check out `etckeeper` for keeping `/etc/` under version control.

Comment: Do you have os-prober installed? I'd install it and retry "update-grub" to see if Windows is recognized.

Comment: I'm no expert on GRUB2, which is a pain in the rear. But the logic is that GRUB2 hands off the boot to Windows, I think. You should check that the root partition (`(hd0,msdos1)`) is correct. Have you? Can you paste the output of `lsblk`, please? That gives the partition layout.

Comment: @FaheemMitha This is the output of ``lsblk``: http://pastebin.com/mpN9ipMq


@no_choice99 I tried that, no luck :/

Comment: @zynphull Put it in the question, please. And try `lsblk -f` instead.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I added it to the question, but here's the output for`` lsblk -f``  http://pastebin.com/eGgnMLUC

Comment: @zynphull No, I meant paste the output into the question. Never mind, I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to solve it by following Christian_Sosa's answer at [MS support](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/the-boot-configuration-data-for-your-pc-is-missing/2cff8cea-bbac-4929-9d36-a349a6c64324), basically run `chkdsk` on the windows drives and then try startup repair. In my case, `chkdsk` did the trick.

1. Boot "Repair" mode from a Windows 10 install disk.
2. Launch the command prompt
3. Type the following commands:

   - `diskpart`

     > This will launch the disk partition utility, we will want to know the volume disk letter for where our OS is located.
   - `list volume`

     > It should list your HDD as well as their drive letter. Remember the drive letter that is in a HDD that most resembles the storage capacity. It may or may not say "boot" for file description.

In my case, I had to repeat this process both for `C:` and `D:` drives, though both had very different sizes.

- `exit`

  > In order to run the next command we will need to exit the disk partition utility.
- `chkdsk /f X:`

  > replace X for your boot os drive letter that we confirmed earlier.

  4. Reboot the system back into the Recovery disc.
  5. Choose Startup Repair and let it run.

In my case, Startup repair never actually ran, but I tried anyway. It seems `chkdsk` alone did the trick. And for the record, the correct grub menuentry in my case was

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
  set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
  chainloader +1
}
```

Thanks for the answers and comments.

Comment: Does that mean it was a Windows corruption issue? If so, any idea why the entry disappeared from GRUB2?

Comment: No idea why it disappeared. To be frank, I can't even be sure it was _precisely_ after I updated Ubuntu that the grub entry disappeared. It could've been something else and I just didn't notice (because I just hadn't used Windows in a while). As for the Windows issue, I suppose we can only guess: maybe the update (or whatever it was) screwed up not only grub, but also the windows bootmgr, thus forcing me to fix both.

Comment: Ok. Well, that's why people put `/etc` under version control. Your GRUB2 config is controlled by files in `/etc`. So, if it is under version control, you'll know when the files changed. Check out `etckeeper`, which does precisely this.

Comment: Will look into ``etckeeper``. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem while updating Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04.

Boot Ubuntu from a live USB/CD and install Boot Repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

If it doesn't gets repaired automatically by boot-repair, then you may try it again and at the end of the process play with "Advanced options".

Comment: As I said, I already tried using boot-repair, and nothing changed.

Comment: Did you tried to tweek advanced options..? I heard of some users that made it work thanks to that...

Comment: Yeah, no luck either, I even tried selecting Windows as the default boot option or something, and nothing changed, still no "Windows" option in grub.